# Javascript function only works for some of the DIVs in a class

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a gallery that toggles between two pictures when the toggle button is pressed. When I press the toggle button, the function only works for 5 of the 6 divs even though they all have the same class. Any idea of what I could be doing wrong? The code is as follows:

HTML

```
<div id="gallery-t-group" class="royalSlider rsDefaultInv">
        <div id="cf1" class="shadow">
            <img class="toggleImg bottom" src="../images/color-picker/ballroom_nospot/1.jpg" />
            <img class="toggleImg top" src="../images/color-picker/ballroom/1.jpg" />
            <img class="rsTmb" width="56" height="56" src="../images/color-picker/thumbs/1.jpg">
        </div>
        <div id="cf2" class="shadow">
            <img class="toggleImg bottom" src="../images/color-picker/ballroom_nospot/2.jpg" />
            <img class="toggleImg top" src="../images/color-picker/ballroom/2.jpg" />
            <img class="rsTmb" width="56" height="56" src="../images/color-picker/thumbs/2.jpg">
        </div>
        <div id="cf3" class="shadow">
            <img class="toggleImg bottom" src="../images/color-picker/ballroom_nospot/3.jpg" />
            <img class="toggleImg top" src="../images/color-picker/ballroom/3.jpg" />
            <img class="rsTmb" width="56" height="56" src="../images/color-picker/thumbs/3.jpg">
        </div>                
        <div id="cf4" class="shadow">
            <img class="toggleImg bottom" src="../images/color-picker/ballroom_nospot/4.jpg" />
            <img class="toggleImg top" src="../images/color-picker/ballroom/4.jpg" />
            <img class="rsTmb" width="56" height="56" src="../images/color-picker/thumbs/4.jpg">
        </div>                
        <div id="cf5" class="shadow">
            <img class="toggleImg bottom" src="../images/color-picker/ballroom_nospot/5.jpg" />
            <img class="toggleImg top" src="../images/color-picker/ballroom/5.jpg" />
            <img class="rsTmb" width="56" height="56" src="../images/color-picker/thumbs/5.jpg">
        </div>                
        <div id="cf6" class="shadow">
            <img class="toggleImg bottom" src="../images/color-picker/ballroom_nospot/6.jpg" />
            <img class="toggleImg top" src="../images/color-picker/ballroom/6.jpg" />
            <img class="rsTmb" width="56" height="56" src="../images/color-picker/thumbs/6.jpg">
        </div>                
</div>
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="cf_onclick" data-toggle="button" aria-pressed="false" autocomplete="off">Pin Spot Toggle</button></div>
```

JavaScript:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $("#cf_onclick").click(function() {
    $(".shadow img.top").toggleClass("transparent");
});
});
```

Comment: which divs work and which don't?

Comment: I can't reproduce the problem you claim happens based on the code you posted. Please create a [mcve] that reproduces the issue.

Comment: How do you tell if the function is working or not? Have you tried to inspect DOM after running this function? Or simply check if  `$('.shadow img.top').length === $('.shadow img.top.transparent').length`

Comment: I tested it and did not notice any issue.  Here's a link to it in JSFiddle. https://jsfiddle.net/kkv8cedr/

Comment: Are you for certain all of the images are named properly and in the correct location?